# How much bandwidth does a running validator use?

Tags: validators

I know running a validator currently requires upwards of 20 GB of disk space. How about bandwidth?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just checked, NetHogs shows me **~30 KB/sec upload** and **~40 KB/sec download** for my `stellar-core` instance (validator without archiver role).

Comment: Sounds about right. My instance in downloading/uploading around 2.5/3GB per day.

Comment: Could you do me a favor and also check the current DB size of horizon? If it's not too much trouble I would also love a snapshot of the table index sizes (see https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/horizon-database-size-are-there-very-large-indexes-yet). I am trying to determine required disk space + RAM for our full validator + horizon nodes. I was told Horizon currently needs 300GB disk space already. So I am leaning towards a 12TB drive for the DB to not have to deal with low disk space it for a while. Curious about RAM as well as I'd prefer to load all indexes to memory easily.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the bandwidth usage of my Stellar Core v9.1.0 validating instance (not writing to any history archive) for 6 hours after startup:

[image: Bandwidth]

RAM usage increases over time. At least 2GB is a requirement, otherwise you'll have to restart your node continuously.
CPU usage varies. While 1 virtual thread of a VPS is generally sufficient, Stellar Core will take advantage of up to 3<sup>1</sup> hardware threads<sup>2</sup>.
For non-archiving validators, disk IO is minimal, while archiving ones usually publish to another host. An SSD drive does the job, anyway.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The peer connections and the history system are all in their own thread, and the main logic all takes place in one thread. ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLhQo.png))

<sup>2</sup> Many Intel processors have a feature called [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which allows for more than 1 software thread to be executed on a given core at the same time. For example, a processor on which each core can execute 2 such threads in parallel is said to have 2 hardware threads per core. On processors without this feature the total number of hardware threads equals the number of cores.</sub>

Comment: Interesting, your bandwidth is significantly higher than the accepted answer's.