# Effects of a stellar-core node running on too slow hardware?

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

What are the effects of running a stellar-core node on slow/weak hardware, e.g. not meeting [stellar-core hw requirements](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/764/hardware-os-requirements-recommendations-for-running-a-full-validator-node)?

Does that create a problem for consensus? If so, are only those affected, who use this slow node as validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the node cannot catch up, it will fall behind in the ledger state.  This is a problem for anyone who uses horizon on that node.  However, it would only be a problem for consensus if other nodes placed the slow node in their quorum slices, which they are unlikely to do if you can't keep up with the network.

Comment: Is there an overview that shows which nodes sometimes "fall behind"? Couldn't find it here https://stellarbeat.io/nodes/GD7FVHL2KUTUYNOJFRUUDJPDRO2MAZJ5KP6EBCU6LKXHYGZDUFBNHXQI or here https://dashboard.stellar.org/